# Conditionally map through rows in CSV file in Scala / Spark to produce another CSV file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, etl

I am quite new to Scala / Spark and I have been thrown into the deep end. I have been trying hard since several weeks to find a solution for a seemingly simple problem on Scala 2.11.8 but have been unable to find a good solution for it.
I have a large database in csv format close to 150 GB, with plenty of null values, which needs to be reduced and cleaned based on the values of individual columns.

The schema of the original CSV file is as follows:

- Column 1: Double
- Columnn 2: Integer
- Column 3: Double
- Column 4: Double
- Columnn 5: Integer
- Column 6: Double
- Columnn 7: Integer

So, I want to conditionally map through all the rows of the CSV file and export the results to another CSV file with the following conditions for each row:

1. If the value for column 4 is not null, then the values for columns 4, 5, 6 and 7 of that row should be stored as an array called lastValuesOf4to7. (In the dataset if the element in column 4 is not null, then columns 1, 2 and 3 are null and can be ignored)
2. If the value of column 3 is not null, then the values of columns 1, 2 and 3 and the four elements from the lastValuesOf4to7 array, as described above, should be exported as a new row into another CSV file called condensed.csv. (In the dataset if the element in column 3 is not null, then columns 4, 5, 6 & 7 are null and can be ignored)

So in the end I should get a csv file called condensed.csv, which has 7 columns.

I have tried using the following code in Scala but have not been able to progress further:

```
import scala.io.Source

object structuringData {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val data = Source.fromFile("/path/to/file.csv") 

  var lastValuesOf4to7 = Array("0","0","0","0")

  val lines = data.getLines // Get the lines of the file

  val splitLine = lines.map(s => s.split(',')).toArray // This gives an out of memory error since the original file is huge.



  data.close
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I have tried to move it into an array but have been unable to progress further since I am unable to process each line individually.

I am quite certain that there must be straightforward solution to processing csv files on Scala / Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response. I managed to create a solution myself using Bash Script. I had to start with a blank condensed.csv file first. My code shows how easy it was to achieve this:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
last1=0
last2=0
last3=0
last4=0
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
    if [[ $f4 != "" ]];
    then 
        last1=$f4
        last2=$f5
        last3=$f6
        last4=$f7

    elif [[ $f3 != "" ]];
    then 
        echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$last1,$last2,$last3,$last4" >> path/to/condensed.csv
    fi

done < $1
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If the script is saved with the name extractcsv.sh then it should be run using the following format:

```
$ ./extractcsv.sh path/to/original/file.csv
```

This only goes to confirm my observation that ETL is easier on Bash than in Scala. Thank you for your help, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Spark-csv package and then use the Sql query to query the data and make the filters according to your use case and then export it at the end.

If you are using spark 2.0.0 then spark-csv will be present in spark-sql or else if you are using a old version add the dependency accordingly.

You can find a link to the [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) here.

You can also look at the example here: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/analysing-csv-data-in-spark/

Comment: Thank you for your response, Shivansh. I am not yet familiar with spark-sql and will have to figure that one out. I am using Spark 1.6.1 for Hadoop 2.6.

Comment: @Moose : I have updated my answer with the link to the example. If you find the answer good enough please upvote and accept ! thanks :)